# Parametrized JBehave tests

Tags: java, maven, testing, jbehave

I have a story with parameters:

```
Given save in the <fileName> the data from <sqlQuery>
Then...

Examples:
fileName    |sqlQuery
file.txt    |query1
```

I run my test on particular environment with maven `-Denvironment=DEV`.
Now I would like to run this test on UAT using `-Denvironment=UAT` but the problem is that the sqlQuery is different then. How to indicate in the java code that if `-Denvironment=DEV` then use query1 but if `-Denvironment=UAT` then use query2 using JBEHAVE stories?

Does anyone cen help me with that?

Comment: The simplest answer is you write another story.  The complicated answer is you either use filter annotations and/or your change your underlying code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest and clanest way is to provide different parameters for each environment directly in the story/scenario, 
and pick a proper parameter in the java code depending on the  environment.
We are using this method for 3 test environments: DEV, UAT, PRE and it work for us very well.
When the story failed then you do not neet to dig into logs or implementation to find which value of the parameter was used, everything is visible in JBehave report.
Also changing parameters is easier, the tester just changes the story, he does not need to look into the implemetation in code.

```
Given save in the <fileName> the data from the query: 
- DEV:<DevSqlQuery> UAT:<UatSqlQuert> PREPROD:<PreSqlQuery>
Then...

Examples:
|fileName    |DevSqlQuery|UatSqlQuery|PreSqlQuery|
|file.txt    |query1     |query2     |query3     |
```